# Eclipse not updating apk when changes made to phonegap app

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

This question has being asked but none of the answers work such as clean,refresh, change version numbers etc.
Eclipse is not rebuilding the android project when changes are made to the source files. It's a phonegap app and if i change html files or even the java code, I still get the same apk!! If i change the version number, that change is reflected but not any other change. Driving me nuts!Any help would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not very clear about what you're really doing, I will try to guess (next time please provide more details if you want to get help).

I will assume you created a cordova 3.x project using the cli, added the android platform and then imported the platforms/android project in eclipse (at this step I hope you didn't check the "copy projects into workspace" option).

Then you modify html/javascript files in the projectroot/www folder and those changes are not reflected when you go in eclipse and create the apk.

Excuse me if my guess is wrong, but if if it's not, I think you're missing a step in the process.

Here is what you should do (if you created the project using phonegap cli and not cordova, please replace cordova with phonegap in the following command) :

- make your changes in the projectroot/www folder
- run the command `cordova prepare android`
- go in eclipse and refresh the project
- build the apk in eclipse

Answer (score 3):

You can automate the execution of the prepare command and the refresh, so wherever you save a file your android application is automatically updated. Notice you have to work with the resources located in the www link folder **within the android application project**.

- Click on the Options of your eclipse project and go to Builders.
- Click on New to add a new Builder.
- Select Program.
- In Main Tab, set:

  - **/usr/bin/cordova** in the location.
  - In the working directory specify the root directory of your project.
  - **prepare android** in arguments
- In the Refresh Tab, activate the "Refresh resources upon completion".
- Finally in the "Build Options" tab, activate the "During auto build" options to execute this new Builder when you save a resource.

And that's all, now your android application will be always updated.

Comment: ey, **Options** called **Preferences** this should cause problems for those who not familiar with eclipse

Comment: Thank you @jalogar, now it's working!

Some tips for Windows users:
this is how I figured out the installation directory of cordova (installed using npm): On the command line type in 'where cordova';; 
Main Tab location: 'C:\Users\YOUR_WINDOWS_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova.cmd' (replace YOUR_WINDOWS_USERNAME with your windows user name);; 
Main Tab working directory: '${workspace_loc:/Workshop}' where 'Workshop' is the name of your project in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case somebody has my rare issue...

I just had this problem, but realized that the timestamp on my apk was in the future. I had recently fixed the date on my machine after generating at least 1 new apk, and the newer timestamp prevented the apk update.

Comment: Thanks for making me check timestamp... My libgame.so file was running 5 hours ahead of time. deleted that and rebuilt fixed it... and it might have got fixed tomorrow automatically. I would have never known what happened.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem

```
    cordova prepare
    cordova build
```

refreshed project as well
nothing worked
then i have deleted apk in

```
    platforms/android/bin/hellocordova-debug.apk
```

then my changes in index.html and home.html are visible on my device.