# change html file but apk not update in cordova

Tags: android, html, eclipse, cordova

I am new in use phonegap, i create an app but i don't know how can i change html file to my purpose? when i changed index html file in www folder in HelloWorld/www and run again program via Eclipse, i see defualt apk file, i dont see any changes! I want to write a sample app for send and receive SMS but i can't, i can't change html file. Can you help me? or send a simple tutorial about create and change js or html file in www folder?

If i cant create this or simple change this, phonegap is not a good thing for use cross platform!

Thanks for your advises :)

Comment: clean your project and delete cache and data of previously installed apk..

Comment: and for set permission for send sms or read data from sd card , i should use CLI? i checked this tomorrow and say to you . If you a simple tutorial step by step for create send and recieve sms, please send to me. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you make changes in the root www folder, you won't see changes in eclipse or apk built by eclipse unless you run `cordova prepare` or `cordova build` to copy the files from /www/ to /platforms/android/assets/www.

Comment: i should run cordova prepare on cmd and refresh an app and uninstall app from my device and then work! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can automate the execution of the prepare command and the refresh, take a look at this response:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25361187/591254

Answer (score 0):

Check files permissions, the project files must have your user permissions.